# How many kernels are used for 2D convolution on multiple input channels?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I understand how kernels work respective to convolutional operations. I'm confused as to how many kernels are used within each operation. Let's say an input image is 256x256x3 and I pass it though a 2D convolutional layer of 32 output channels. Is each output channel created by convolving the same kernel across all 3 input channels or by convolving a different kernel across each of the 3 input channels? In other words, does this operation use 96 or 32 different kernels to produce 32 channels?

```
i = Input(shape=(256,256,3))
x = Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu') (i)
```

Answer (score 0):

An output channel is created by convolving a kernel with the ENTIRE input.

But please notice that although you set the kernel size to `3x3` the actual kernel is not 2D but 3D like `3*3*c` where `c` is the number of input channels.

To put it in different words, each kernel has `c` 2D filters each which is applied to its corresponding channel, obtaining `c` values (one per input channel) which are added up to give the a single value in one of the output channels. so they are 32 kernels, but if you want to say they are actually 96 2D filters you are not really wrong, since the 2D filters within the kernel are independent from one another.

Please refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTB_OFoAQcc) by Andrew NJ for a better explanation.

Comment: Can you add an example of input shape and output shape of tensors?